# What is an epoch and how is related to steps and batch_size?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have looked through other solution to the similar questions but none gave a complete explanation. For my understanding, the epoch is a test round in which the test-set divided in 'm' batch_size goes under 'n' steps. And in this case, no of epochs will be the size(data-set)/m.

Ok, but what if the batch_size was equal to the size(data-set), then how to decide the number of the epochs.I faced the similar problem when going through the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/get_started).

```
import numpy as np

x_train = np.array([1., 2., 3., 4.])
y_train = np.array([0., -1., -2., -3.])
x_eval = np.array([2., 5., 8., 1.])
y_eval = np.array([-1.01, -4.1, -7, 0.])
input_fn = tf.contrib.learn.io.numpy_input_fn(
    {"x":x_train}, y_train,batch_size=4, num_epochs=1000)
eval_input_fn = tf.contrib.learn.io.numpy_input_fn(
    {"x":x_eval}, y_eval, batch_size=4, num_epochs=1000)
```

Here the batch_size is equal to the size(data-set).
So what's the real related behind these terms.Please explain with a well-defined example..

Answer (score 1):

Commonly, those terms are interpreted as such:

**Epoch**: A full pass over your dataset. In the evaluation case, typically you'll go though your test set once (thus, for one epoch). In training, however, it's common to train the estimator on the same dataset multiple times (and thus having a number of epochs greater than 1).

**Batch** (also sometimes referred to as *minibatch*): A group of samples processed together, whose resulting weights updates are averaged before being applied in the learning step for Stochastic Gradient Descent optimization methods.

**Step**: One step of your algorithm, which processes one batch of data.

### An example with numbers

Let's say you have **300 samples** in your dataset.
When you train an estimator, you'll have to decide a batch size. The learning algorithm averages the weight updates coming from every example in a batch and takes only **one step per batch** updating the weights with the (discounted) average of the weight updates (thus the definition of *step* above).
Typically in the case of big networks (I worked with Inception models) the suggestion is to take as big a batch size as it fits in the memory of the device you're training on, but you should definitely experiment with different batch sizes and find what works best for you.

Let's assume that in our example we choose a **batch size of 30**. This means we'll cover the whole dataset in **300/30 = 10 steps per Epoch**. After 10 steps, we'll have completed an epoch. Should we continue with steps 11-20, that'd be the *second* epoch, in which we go through the dataset a second time.

**- Note:** if the batch size doesn't exactly divide your dataset size, you have two possibilities: either you skip the last samples and consider only full batches, or you allow forthe last batch to be smaller thanthe others. Tensorflow has methods to handle both cases (although as far as I know by default it only considers full epochs).

Comment: So in the above example, there would be 1000 (i.e. ((data-set)/m)*epochs) different gradient-descent calculated and their average is used to evaluate the x_eval.

Comment: See the example I added, this shold clarify things a bit

Comment: (Edited a bunch of times to fix typos and the numbers in the example. Now it has the right numbers)